# What adapter should I specify in database.yml while using neoid with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am using neoid with rails. Currently I am forced to use sqlite3 together with neo4j because I haven't yet figured out how to use only neo4j in my project. I guess I need to know which adapter should I specify in database.yml for neoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on my question:
https://github.com/elado/neoid/issues/9
There is no way to use neoid without regular database (such as MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite).